# Cypress.io: Server Error | 404 - File or director not found

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress, dms, opentext

I'm currently trying to automate the test for a pretty big webapplication (DMS) Document Management System. To explain the system a little bit: There is a loadbalancer which connect to one of two frontends. To be sure that will be no problems in my test I directly try to access frontend one. Now to my problem:

When trying to run all the tests (around 20 spec-Files) with the Test Runner and also when trying to run the tests via console with the following command: `.\node_modules\.bin\cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/Basis/**/*" --browser chrome`

Sometimes after a `cy.visit()` a Server Error comes up. That error also stops the tests on console from running and looks like it crashes cypress. The error is the following:
[image]

It's not possible that the resource is missing or somewhere else because most of the times the test works. Most of the time its a different test where the error comes up. The worst part is that I have no idea how to reproduce that error. And it looks like that problem is only appearing for me.

So please tell me if you have ever seen this message and maybe you can help me fix this problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: A side question: Is the mix of slashes and backlslashes in url ok? What happens if you replace your backslashes by slashes?

Comment: @Reporter I used backslashes because I'm working on windows. Forward slashes work too apparently...

Comment: Judging from the screenshot your app runs on IIS it'd be better to see what's happening if you could have a look at the IIS logs. Perhaps the app restarts (recycles) itself and when it does it  results with 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in Cypress which causes usages of `window.location.href` and other `Location` methods to incorrectly use `/__/` as the base URL.

You can try enabling the `experimentalSourceRewriting` config option to work around this, read here for more info: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/experiments.html#Configuration

Comment: Thank you very much I will try that. Hopefully solves the problem for me and gets fixed with a future release.

Comment: I think it works better but sadly the Error still appears sometimes... And when I run all the tests with a .bat-Script the script still gets stopped after the error... So the only thing that I can do is hope that it gets fixed?

Comment: Pretty much @WasteD, 5.4.0 will contain some improvements to the `experimentalSourceRewriting` feature to make it work on more domains.

Comment: Hmm sadly I'm already using version 5.4.0 and that doesn't solve it for me but thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 5.5.0/5.4.1 - the next release  it was a long day.

Comment: Ok now after the update it seems to be working. I didn't read anything specific in the Changelog I even removed ```experimentalSourceReqriting``` and its still working.