# Cypress runner gives me a 404 when using Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, testing, firefox, cypress

This issue seems somewhat related to [Cypress.io: Server Error | 404 - File or director not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64390753/cypress-io-server-error-404-file-or-director-not-found) but the solution provided did not work for me.

I can run my tests in Cypress runner fine with Chrome, Electron and Edge but when I attempt to run a test in Firefox I'm getting a 404. I'm using FF 86

I enabled experimentalSourceRewriting in my cypress.json file but it's still failing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Zscaler and some scripts that were changing the Firefox proxy.